# How to create zoom animation effect for custom view

Tags: android

Currently, I have a custom view which represents a pie chart.

```
public class PieChart extends View {
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
```

With the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >

    <org.yccheok.jstock.gui.charting.PieChart
```

It looks like this (The custom pie chart view is the top half view, which its width is fill_parent, and its height is 50% of parent)

[image]

When the activity being launched, I'm looking forward to have a pie chart zoom animation similar to this

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwGoSswCZhQ

I had read http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/zoom.html. The example is using 2 images (one is scale down version, another is scaled up version) to achieve such effect.

*I'm not exactly sure how can I apply them in my case? Do I need to construct 2 version pie charts as well? (one is scale down version, another is normal size version)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the good old `ScaleAnimation` to achieve this effect. Here is an example which scales a view from 20% to 100%. The scale origin is set to the center of the view.

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(600);
pieChart.startAnimation(set);
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html for the full documentation.