# Creating Zoom animation from center of view for custom scale

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to create a zoom animation for a view. I want the animation from the centre of the view for the custom scale.
Tried following three approaches but none seems to work

(1) Got some ideas from http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html and tried creating the animation

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentLayer, View.SCALE_X, currentScaleX, newScaleX))
    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentLayer, View.SCALE_Y, currentScaleY, newScaleY));
// various ways to animate PivotX/PivotY or set pivots did not help
set.setDuration(500);
set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        adjustScale();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        adjustScale();
    }
});
```

The animation does happen but not from the center of view, Various ways to set pivots did not help

(2) Tried xml based approach to create animation, but could not find a way to specify custom scale values from code
[zoom in and zoom out animation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904432/zoom-in-and-zoom-out-animation-in-android)
zoom.xml

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1" >
</scale>
```

// Animation class do not support changing from and to scales,

(3)
Tried directly creating ScaleAnimation with scale and pivot http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html
Looked at this as well [How to create zoom animation effect for custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765275/how-to-create-zoom-animation-effect-for-custom-view)
but animation did not even happen

Can some one suggest a solution that works for this case`enter code here`

Comment: u  done how it can be achieved ? http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2qx2if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by writing custom animation. The issue was that we were handing all view updates ourselves and not using android's layouting capabilities. So when we used android animators, the pivots were always 0,0